# Problems in implementing adaptive thresholding using CUDA

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

If you run the code below, the applied image will look like this: What do I need to fix to make it work correctly?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

// CUDA kernel function
__global__ void adaptiveThresholdCUDA(const uchar* image, uchar* binary, const int* iimage, int nl, int nc, int halfSize, int blockSize, int threshold) {
    // Calculate global indices
    int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    // Check boundary conditions
    if (j >= nl - halfSize - 1 || i >= nc - halfSize - 1)
        return;

    // Get row addresses
    const uchar* data = image + j * nc;
    uchar* binaryRow = binary + j * nc;
    const int* idata1 = iimage + (j - halfSize) * nc;
    const int* idata2 = iimage + (j + halfSize + 1) * nc;

    // Calculate sum
    int sum = (idata2[i + halfSize + 1] - idata2[i - halfSize] - idata1[i + halfSize + 1] + idata1[i - halfSize]) / (blockSize * blockSize);

    // Apply adaptive threshold
    if (data[i] < (sum - threshold))
        binaryRow[i] = 0;
    else
        binaryRow[i] = 255;
}

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("image/test.jpg", 0);
    if (!image.data) return 0;

    resize(image, image, Size(), 1.0, 1.0);
    namedWindow("Original Image");
    imshow("Original Image", image);

    /*          Function for Adaptive Thresholding          */
    int blockSize = 16; // Neighborhood size
    int threshold = 10; // Pixel comparison threshold

    Mat binary = image.clone();

    int nl = binary.rows; // Number of lines
    int nc = binary.cols; // Total number of elements per line

    Mat iimage;
> integral(image, iimage, CV_32S);

    // Allocate memory on device (GPU)
    uchar* imageDevice;
    uchar* binaryDevice;
    int* iimageDevice;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&imageDevice, sizeof(uchar) * nl * nc);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&binaryDevice, sizeof(uchar) * nl * nc);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&iimageDevice, sizeof(int) * nl * nc);

    // Copy input data from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(imageDevice, image.data, sizeof(uchar) * nl * nc, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(binaryDevice, binary.data, sizeof(uchar) * nl * nc, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(iimageDevice, iimage.data, sizeof(int) * nl * nc, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Define grid and block dimensions
    dim3 blockDim(16, 16);  // You may need to adjust the block dimensions
    dim3 gridDim((nc + blockDim.x - 1) / blockDim.x, (nl + blockDim.y - 1) / blockDim.y);

    // Launch the CUDA kernel
    adaptiveThresholdCUDA << <gridDim, blockDim >> > (imageDevice, binaryDevice, iimageDevice, nl, nc, blockSize / 2, blockSize, threshold);

}
```

[image: Original image]

[image: Output image from adaptive thresholding]

When changing the size of `blockDim` and applying it, if it is set too large or too small, it may not be applied.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `iimage` has one extra row and one extra column compared to `image`.

According to the documentation of [cv::integral](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gadeaf38d7701d7ad371278d663c50c77d):

> src - input image as W×H, 8-bit or floating-point (32f or 64f).
> sum - integral image as (W+**1**)×(H+**1**) , 32-bit integer or floating-point (32f or 64f).

The image size of the posted sample is `332` columns by `302` rows.
The image size `iimage` is `333` columns by `303` rows.

---

We have to copy `iimage` to device with one more row and column:

```
int iimage_nl = iimage.rows; // = nl + 1
int iimage_nc = iimage.cols; // = nc + 1

cudaMalloc((void**)&iimageDevice, sizeof(int) * iimage_nl * iimage_nc);

cudaMemcpy(iimageDevice, iimage.data, sizeof(int) * iimage_nl * iimage_nc, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

---

We have to fix the kernel according to the actual size of `iimage`:

```
__global__ void adaptiveThresholdCUDA(...) {
    ...
    int iimage_nc = nc + 1; //Number of columns in iimage equals (nc+1)
    
    const int* idata1 = iimage + (j - halfSize) * iimage_nc;
    const int* idata2 = iimage + (j + halfSize + 1) * iimage_nc;
    ...
```

---

Updated code sample:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
//#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


// CUDA kernel function
__global__ void adaptiveThresholdCUDA(const uchar* image, uchar* binary, const int* iimage, int nl, int nc, int halfSize, int blockSize, int threshold) {
    // Calculate global indices
    int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    // Check boundary conditions
    if (j >= nl - halfSize - 1 || i >= nc - halfSize - 1)
        return;

    // Get row addresses
    int iimage_nc = nc + 1; //Number of columns in iimage equals (nc+1)
    const uchar* data = image + j * nc;
    uchar* binaryRow = binary + j * nc;
    const int* idata1 = iimage + (j - halfSize) * iimage_nc;
    const int* idata2 = iimage + (j + halfSize + 1) * iimage_nc;

    // Calculate sum
    int sum = (idata2[i + halfSize + 1] - idata2[i - halfSize] - idata1[i + halfSize + 1] + idata1[i - halfSize]) / (blockSize * blockSize);

    // Apply adaptive threshold
    if (data[i] < (sum - threshold))
        binaryRow[i] = 0;
    else
        binaryRow[i] = 255;
}

int main()
{
    //Mat image = imread("image/test.jpg", 0);
    Mat image = imread("test.png", 0);
    if (!image.data) return 0;

    resize(image, image, Size(), 1.0, 1.0);
    namedWindow("Original Image");
    imshow("Original Image", image);

    /*          Function for Adaptive Thresholding          */
    int blockSize = 16; // Neighborhood size
    int threshold = 10; // Pixel comparison threshold

    Mat binary = image.clone();

    //nl = 332, nc = 302
    int nl = binary.rows; // Number of lines
    int nc = binary.cols; // Total number of elements per line

    Mat iimage;
    integral(image, iimage, CV_32S);

    //https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gadeaf38d7701d7ad371278d663c50c77d
    //src   input image as W×H, 8-bit or floating-point (32f or 64f).
    //sum   integral image as (W+1)×(H+1) , 32-bit integer or floating-point (32f or 64f).
    //iimage_nl = 333, iimage_nc = 303
    int iimage_nl = iimage.rows; // = nl + 1
    int iimage_nc = iimage.cols; // = nc + 1

    // Allocate memory on device (GPU)
    uchar* imageDevice;
    uchar* binaryDevice;
    int* iimageDevice;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&imageDevice, sizeof(uchar) * nl * nc);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&binaryDevice, sizeof(uchar) * nl * nc);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&iimageDevice, sizeof(int) * iimage_nl * iimage_nc);

    // Copy input data from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(imageDevice, image.data, sizeof(uchar) * nl * nc, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(binaryDevice, binary.data, sizeof(uchar) * nl * nc, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(iimageDevice, iimage.data, sizeof(int) * iimage_nl * iimage_nc, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Define grid and block dimensions
    dim3 blockDim(16, 16);  // You may need to adjust the block dimensions
    dim3 gridDim((nc + blockDim.x - 1) / blockDim.x, (nl + blockDim.y - 1) / blockDim.y);

    // Launch the CUDA kernel
    adaptiveThresholdCUDA<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(imageDevice, binaryDevice, iimageDevice, nl, nc, blockSize / 2, blockSize, threshold);


    Mat output = image.clone();
    cudaMemcpy(output.data, binaryDevice, sizeof(uchar) * nl * nc, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); //Copy from device to host
    imshow("Output Image", output);
    waitKey();
    destroyAllWindows();

    imwrite("output.png", output);  //Save the output
}
```

---

`test.png` (input image):
[image]

`output.png` (output image):
[image]

---

Note that the above solution just demonstrates a possible solution (the intention is to show why the output image is "slanted").

Comment: Thanks! I slove this problem!

Comment: Do you know how to mark an answer as "accepted answer"?